# HTTP request, strange socket behaviour

Tags: http, sockets, gzip

I experience strange behavior when doing HTTP requests through sockets, here the request:

```
POST https://example.com:443/service/XMLSelect HTTP/1.1
Content-Length: 10926
Host: example.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 1.0.3705)
Authorization: Basic XXX
SOAPAction: http://example.com/SubmitXml
```

Later on there goes body of my request with given content length.
After that I receive something like:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Tue, 30 Mar 2010 06:13:52 GMT
```

So everything seem to be fine here. I read all contents from network stream and successfully receive response. But my socket which I'm doing polling on switches it's modes like that:

```
write ( i write headers and request here )
read ( after headers sent i begin to receive response )
write ( STRANGE BEHAVIOUR HERE. WHY? here i send nothing really )
read ( here it switches to read back again )
```

last two steps can repeat several times. So I want to ask what leads for socket's mode change? And in this case it's not a big problem, but when I use gzip compression in my request ( no idea how it's related ) and ask server to send gzipped response to me like this:

```
POST https://example.com:443/service/XMLSelect HTTP/1.1
Content-Length: 1076
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Content-Encoding: gzip
Host: example.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 1.0.3705)
Authorization: Basic XXX
SOAPAction: http://example.com/SubmitXml
```

I receive response like that:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Tue, 30 Mar 2010 07:26:33 GMT

2000
�
```

I receive a chunk size and GZIP header, it's all okay. And here's what is happening with my poor little socket meanwhile:

```
write ( i write headers and request here )
read ( after headers sent i begin to receive response )
write ( STRANGE BEHAVIOUR HERE. And it finally sits here forever waiting for me to send something! But if i refer to HTTP I don't have to send anything more! )
```

What can it be related to? What it wants me to send? Is it remote web server's problem or do I miss something?

PS All actual service references and login/passwords replaced with fake ones :)

Comment: Small point, but sample URLs should use one of the RFC2606 reserved domains [http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2606.txt] such as example.com - which are guaranteed never to point to a live domain if someone ever copy/pastes the sample code anywhere that does anything

Comment: Ops, I'm sorry, replaced with correct ones :) What about my question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A socket becomes *writable* whenever there's space in the socket *send buffer*. The OS can't really know if your application has more data to send, but knows about its internal structures, like socket buffers. You have to explicitly add/remove the socket to the write `fd_set` for `select(2)` (enable/disable `EPOLLOUT` event for `epoll(4)`). This is usually handled with a *state machine*, like in [libevent](http://www.monkey.org/~provos/libevent/). Also polling works best with *non-blocking* sockets.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks man! =) i actually figured thing about buffer myself, but it's great to see a specialist here!

Comment: is there any way to contact with you if i have some question? :)

Comment: I'm writing my solution on c# and use blocking sockets but read from buffer looping throught sockets in cycle. I guess it's not the best solution but still it shows great performance if compare with async calls using threads. I can handle like 500 sockets with in one thread with not valuable overhead on looping time. And my processor feel just great having only 10% load on average :) I would love to send/recieve from socket directly but i don't want to implement SSL stuff myself and I use SSLStream. If you have any suggestions I would love to hear'em!

Comment: Hey, that's a *very* good start! Threads are often overrated in multi-socket setup and create more problems that they are supposed to solve.  
If you have a question - just post it! There are more experts here every day. I usually pay attention to c/c++/sockets/etc. tags.